# Rails4 Generate Seed Data from Exisitng DB content

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

I have a DB content for location details like Countries, Regions, Cities with the data that amounts to over 50k Records. I wanna generate the Seed file with this data.

I am trying to use this plugin - [seed_dump](https://github.com/rroblak/seed_dump)

But after running rake `db:seed:dump` nothing seems to happen.

Do i need to to create models before i do the dump?

Is there a way i can create Models based on the existing MySQL tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `rails 4.1` with `ruby 2.1.1` and this gem works perfectly with 5k records.
Yep, you must create models, before use this gem. Or try dump database to yml-file.

Comment: i do not have the models i guess thats the problem. is there a way to generate the models from the tables that exisits from the database?

Comment: any plugin to dump it to yml file? the yaml_db is only for rails3